# MsSQL Server for Linux: is SQLDMO / 2005 backward Compatibility available?

Tags: linux, sql-server

Is Ms SQL Server 2005 Backup Compatibility available in Linux environment?

I'm trying to deploy a DB server, based on mssql-server 2017 under Linux, for an accounting software (namely InsERT GT, quite popular in Poland). This software is originally intended to run in all-Microsoft environment, especially with Windows-based MsSQL Server.

The software requires the 2005 Backup Compatibility installed on the DB Server. It looks like the 2005 Compatibility is used with DB backup/restore operations and I guess SQL DMO is the key functionality (only guess, I'm not a DB admin).

Is it possible to have the 2005 backup Compatibility available under Linux?

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Distributed Management Objects (SQL-DMO) is no longer included in
>   SQL Server 2012, SQL-DMO applications should be converted to use SQL
>   Server Management Objects (SMO). 
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/dev-guide/sql-dmo-mapping-to-smo?view=sql-server-2014

So no, on either Windows or Linux.

Looks like the DMO replacement SMO has been available since SQL Server 2005, 14 years ago.